# Differenceses between Nextjs and React when trying to create a form

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am learning react/nextjs and I have come into an issue when following a react tutorial and trying to convert it into nextjs.

I am trying to create a simple form that will submit data so a great tutorial I thought.

The tutorial I am following is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zT62eVxShsY&t=635s @ 12.22

They use:

```
state = {
    step: 1,
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    email: '',
    occupation: '',
    city: '',
    bio: ''
}
```

so I just changed this to:

```
const state = {
    step: 1,
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    email: '',
    occupation: '',
    city: '',
    bio: ''
}
```

which I understand to be correct by I am now doubting myself although it's not throwing up any issues at the moment?

My second issue is:

```
render() {
    const { step } = this.state;
    const { firstName, lastName, email, occupation, city, bio }
}
```

I tried changing this to:

```
return (
    const { step } = this.state;
    const { firstName, lastName, email, occupation, city, bio }
    <div>
        <h1>Form</h1>
    </div>
);
```

But I get the following error for this line `const { step } = this.state;`:

Syntax error: Unexpected token

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my full code:

```
import { render } from "react-dom";

const UserForm = () => {
const state = {
    step: 1,
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    email: '',
    occupation: '',
    city: '',
    bio: ''
}

// Proceed to the next step
const nextStep = () => {
    const { step } = this.state;
    this.setState({
        step: step + 1
    });
}

// Go back to the previous step
const prevStep = () => {
    const { step } = this.state;
    this.setState({
        step: step - 1
    });
}

// Handle fields change
const handleChange = input => e => {
    this.setState({ [input]: e.target.value });
}


return (
    const { step } = this.state;
const { firstName, lastName, email, occupation, city, bio }
<div>
    <h1>Form</h1>
</div>
);
}

export default UserForm;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you may be mixing up functional components and class based components along with a couple other issues.

If you are to stick to the tutorial you linked to, `UseForm` needs to be a class and have to extend the React component, and you will also need the `render` function.

As you can see on the code during [this point on the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zT62eVxShsY&t=8m18s&ab_channel=TraversyMedia)

You need to both import `React` and `Component` to implement a proper component. So basically this:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export class UseForm extends Component {
   ...
}
```

I did also notice you are declaring consts in your return statement. This is incorrect. You don't declare anything in a return statement, it isn't the same as a function, which is what `render` is. To quote from the [MDN return statement docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return),

> The return statement ends function execution and specifies a value to be returned to the function caller.

In the case of a React component, you do just want to return the JSX stuff. So a minimal correction to that would be something like the following:

```js
const { step } = this.state;
const { firstName, lastName, email, occupation, city, bio }

return (
<div>
    <h1>Form</h1>
</div>
);
```

Unfortunately though, this will bring us to the next issues with your code, which is your usage of `this.state` and the fact that you have a deconstructing const, from nothing.

Lets start with `this.state` and `this.setState(...)`, that is the  React component state API used for class based components, which are essentially out of date. If you are going the functional route, you will get errors.

For functional components, you will need to import the [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) and handle them all with that hook. I'll leave that research to you.

Next up is the following statement:

> const { firstName, lastName, email, occupation, city, bio }

I am not sure if this is a typo, or an attempt at declaring a bunch of variables. But when you declare variables with the brackets (`{}`) you are doing a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and it needs to come from another variable.

With all that being said, if you are just starting to learn React and JS, I highly recommend instead of taking a 2018 outdated video and changing it yourself to match more up-to-date React, try to find something more up to date and begin with. It looks like there is [a 2021 version of a react tutorial from that same creator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w7ejDZ8SWv8&ab_channel=TraversyMedia) which may be more productive to take at look.

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth answer. I have marks this as answered because you are right. I did look at his update video but unfortunately there was no form. I will however find a more up today video with a form.

Comment: @Juan-man No problem. Glad to help. Just so you know, usually Traversy Media covers absolutely everything in his crash course videos. He indexed it in the description. He teaches you how to use the form starting at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w7ejDZ8SWv8&t=63m5s&ab_channel=TraversyMedia